# How to export compose preview to png/jpg

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

After creating the compose layout, is there any solution to export the preview to a high definition jpg/png file?

[image]

I want to export *DefaultPreview* to a jpg/png.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

Solved!!

Simply right clicking on preview and click on `Copy Image`

Comment: do you know if there is an programmatically way of doing it?

Comment: @JoãoCarlos I know that there is a cmdline tool named `screenshot` or `screenshot2` but that's for the emulator. in the IDE I haven't searched for such action yet, but you may find it, if there is one... the last way I can think of, is to write a plugin for android studio to do this.

Comment: thanks for the tip, i wanted to add documentation for my components so i needed to take save a picture for each one and then add to a markdown;

Comment: What do you do after "Copy Image"?

Comment: @Jameson paste it on desktop, sometimes creates the file! (interesting!), or simply open an image manipulation program like ms paint (in windows) then paste it there and finally save it where you want :). __Also consider upvoting this answer if it helped you__